# compare files inside containers with files from outside

Tags: docker

My development cycle is I have the sources for the website outside container.
Then I build an image by taking an image prepared with apache, php, etc.
Then copy the www into the image.

Basically

```
FROM myLamp
COPY www /var/www/html
```

This image I use for production, and I run another container for development from it too.
I then run vscode attached to the development container, and occationally I might make emergency changes on the production container too

Can I compare the files from inside with outside? So I know which files to pull out to the master /www I build images from?

Something like `docker container compare <container>:/var/www/html www`

`docker container diff <container>` gives information on which files that's been added/changed/deleted, but not what's been changed.

Comment: If you always `docker build` a new image when you need to do a deployment, `docker rm` the old container, and `docker run` a new one, you'll always be in a consistent state.  Especially especially especially in production, I would not recommend going in and editing things in the container by hand, or else you get problems exactly like this where you're not clear what code is actually running.  This gets even worse if you have a replicated environment and multiple copies of a container; edit code in one and the others will be out of sync.

Comment: My idea is to test stuff in develop container, if it works, I'll copy the changes outside, build a new container with those changes, and deploy that to production. 

If not, I can just remove the container and build a new fresh

Comment: But perhaps I should use git to store the source and pull from git when building new images